# Why does Slick-util's Texture.getWidth() and Texture.getHeight() return a float?

Tags: java, floating-point, textures, lwjgl, pixel

I'm making a game with LWJGL (and Slick-util) and I was going to use the `Texture.getWidth()` and `Texture.getHeight()` to get the width and height of a `Texure` object, instead of typing in the width and height manually, but I found out that those functions returns a `float`. I want to get the width of the `Texture` in pixels, but the function returns a float, so I'm unsure what "unit" the function actually returns, because pixels must be `int` (not floats, because you cant render the half of a pixel with one color and the other half of it with another color).

Can I just cast them to `int` and it's fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the quick asking, I found the answer by looking in the javadocs for Slick-util.

To get the size of the original image, use `Texture.getImageWidth()` and `Texture.getImageHeight()`.